# Difference between Catch(Exception) and Catch(Exception ex)

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

What is the difference between `Catch(Exception)` and `Catch(Exception ex)` . I can see both giving me expected output. Then what is the actual difference ? Which one is recommended ?

Suppose the code is below.

```
int a = 1, b = 0;
try
{
    int c = a / b;
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Which of the below catch block is recommended to use ? What is the actual difference between those ?

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

**OR**

```
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Oh NO!!");
}
```

Comment: If you are not interested in what exception are you catching (info on stack, message etc) you could simply write `catch {Console.WriteLine("Oh No");}`

Comment: The difference is that you'll have *some* idea why your program stops working correctly in the 1st snippet.  None whatsoever in the 2nd snippet.  The 2nd way is what makes SO users ask questions like "it doesn't work, there was an error".  Just don't write code like this at all.

Comment: @Steve There is a tiny difference between `catch` and `catch (Exception)`. The first will catch all exception objects, the second will only catch exceptions objects deriving from `Exception`. In C# you can only throw objects deriving from `Exception`, but the CLR supports more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `catch(Exception ex)` is just the same as `catch(Exception)` with one difference
only: in `catch(Exception ex)` we have an access to the exception class (error cause)
instance. Usually you need an exception class instance to print out the original
message:

```
  try {
    ...
  }
  catch (AppServerException e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Application server failed to get data with the message:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message); // <- What's actually got wrong with it
  }
```

If you don't need the exception class instance, e.g. you plan just to consume the
exception, the catch(Exception ex) syntax is excessive and catch(Exception) is
prefferable:

```
  try {  
    c = a / b;
  }  
  catch (DivideByZeroException) {
    c = Int.MaxValue; // <- in case b = 0, let c be the maximum possible int
  }
```

Finally. *Do not catch a general Exception class without re-throwing*:

```
  try {
    int c = a / b;
  }
  catch (Exception) { // <- Never ever do this!
    Console.WriteLine("Oh NO!!");
  }
```

Do you really want to code "whatever error (green fume from CPU included) had
happened just print out 'Oh No' and continue"?

The pattern with Exception class is something like this:

```
  tran.Start();

  try {
    ...
    tran.Commit();
  }
  catch (Exception) {
    // Whatever had happened, let's first rollback the database transaction
    tran.Rollback();

    Console.WriteLine("Oh NO!");

    throw; // <- re-throw the exception
  }
```

Comment: I disagree with '_Do not catch general Exception class without re-throwing'_. and _'Do you really want to code "whatever error" just print out "Oh No" and continue?'. 1. Sometimes I do 2. There are other things I may want to do (besides logging). It is common to catch `Exception ex` in code.

Comment: It's `DivideByZeroException` not `ZeroDivisonException` afaik.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Sir, what's purpose of line `throw;` I guess it's used to `throw` exception but why we would do that? And what are benefits of doing that? I saw many `catch` statements where there is no `throw` at the end of the `catch`. Thanks

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: `throw;` rethrows the exception; please, note, that in the last sample we've processed the expection *partially* - we rollback the transaction and show message. However, it may *require* some *other actions*, that's we rethrow the exception for high level routine to known that the low level operation failed

Comment: @ DmitryBychenko You mean we are throwing ex because of some higher exception handler which might do some additional actions ? I'm really confused about why is throw used in catch block, for me allways was enought to log the exception and that's it.. but many ppl are putting throw at the end of catch block and I couldn't understand why

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: Yes, additional action may be wanted badly. Imagine, you want to export data to database, if everything is OK you commit changes and, say, csv file is deleted. If not, you should rollback changes (which you should do within the low level code); however that's not all: we should preserve csv intact (it's a function of high level code) and (depending on some settings) send an eMail. Here we completed *our part* of exception handling (rain or shine transaction should be rolled back) and let the very same exception be processed higher

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple:

- in the first code, you can catch the exception and get the object representing it so you can have more information about what happened
- in the second code, you only know that an exception has been raised, but you don't have more information about it.

What to use actually depends on how much information you want to have about the exception raised.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use the exception inside the `catch` block, give `Exception` a name; otherwise, keep it anonymous.

There are situations when the `catch` block needs to do more than simply show exception's message. For example, when you catch application-specific exceptions, you may be able to examine additional elements of the exception object. Here is a hypothetical example:

```
catch (ConnectToServerException cse) {
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format(
        "Connection to server '{0}' failed. Use a name from the following list: {1}"
    ,   cse.AttemptedConnectionServerName
    ,   string.Join(", ", cse.AllowedServerNames)
    ));
}
```

The above code assumes that the custom exception `ConnectToServerException` has a property called `AttemptedConnectionServerName` with the name of the server to which you tried to connect, and an enumeration property `AllowedServerNames` with the names of available servers.

There are also situations when all you need to know is that an exception of a particular type just happened. In this case, you do not need to provide a named variable for it.

Answer (score 0):

`Catch (Exception)` do the same thing, as it is also a `Exception` type.

`Catch (Exception ex)` catches all exceptions and in addition you can retrieve message through its reference.

Use is dependent on requirement, if you want to show exception message you have facility to use `ex.Message` otherwise `Catch (Exception)` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

With `catch(Exception)` you only specify what kind of exception you're gonna handle in that catch block (in this case, any exception that is raised, so it would be the same as just `catch`)

With `catch(Exception ex)` you pass an instance of the actual exception that is raised, so you can access the properties of the exception and do something with the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that one will print *Attempted to divide by zero.* and the other will print *Oh NO!!*.

Handling exceptions is a complex problem and depends on the application, but here are few general comments:

---

Generally speaking it's best to provide handlers for specific exceptions:

Something like:

```
 catch ({System.DivideByZeroException ex )
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Ops. I cannot divide by zero." );
 }
 catch ({System.Exception ex )
 {
    Console.WriteLine("There was an error during calculations: {0}", ex.Message );
 }
```

---

Sooner or later you will find out that `Console.WriteLine` is just not good enough and you will have to use a logger so best to start using it early.

---

Ideally, if you decide to expose raw error messages to the user, you should be printing all messages in the exception chain or at least the one which is most deep.

Something like:

```
 catch ({System.DivideByZeroException ex )
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Oops. I cannot divide by zero." );
 }
 catch ({System.Exception ex )
 {
    Console.WriteLine(GetExceptionMsgs(ex));
 }

 ...in another class...
public static string GetExceptionMsgs(Exception ex) {
   if( ex == null ) {
       return "No exception = no details";
   }
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   while( ex != null ) {
        sb.AppendLine(ex.Message);
        ex = ex.InnerException;
   }
   return sb.ToString()
}
```